# CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation with image not working on Device, works in simulator

Tags: iphone

I tried to add an image annotation to a barplot. It works fine in iOS simulator, but the image annotation not shown on the device.  I am using Xcode 4.2.  Tested on two devices, one is iOS 4.3, another one is iOS5.0.1.

I am using armv7, with Apple LLVM 3.0 compiler. I know the image file name is case sensitive and it's correct.

The piece of code I tried is below:

```
CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *imageAnnotation;
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(50, 50 ,30, 30);
CPTLayer *newImagelLayer = [[CPTLayer alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
newImagelLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] CGImage];
imageAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:plotSpace anchorPlotPoint:nil];
imageAnnotation.contentLayer = newImagelLayer;
[barPlot addAnnotation:imageAnnotation];
[newImagelLayer release];
[imageAnnotation release];
```

Is this a known issue?  I don't understand why it works in simulator but not on device.

Comment: Why do you have newLabelLayer and newImageLayer?

Comment: That's a typo when I put in the question. They are all newImagelLayer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by using CPTFill on CPTBorderedLayer.

```c
CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *imageAnnotation;
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(50, 50 ,30, 30);
CPTBorderedLayer *newImagelLayer = [[CPTBorderedLayer alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
newImagelLayer.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageWithCGImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"dot-selector.png"] CGImage]]];
imageAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:plotSpace anchorPlotPoint:nil];
imageAnnotation.contentLayer = newImagelLayer;
[barPlot addAnnotation:imageAnnotation];
[newImagelLayer release];
[imageAnnotation release];
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have not added `test.png` to the target. This works OK in the simulator, but on the device if a resource is not added to the target, it will not get copied to the ipa file that gets generated.

Check in your target's **Build Phases** tab under **Copy Bundle Resources** if your `test.png` is listed, if not you could just drag and drop it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did double check that, and the image is there. In debug, I can also see the UIImage object is created properly, just not shown on the device's screen.

Answer (score 0):

Is the asset named exactly "test.png" the file system in OSX is case insensitive, iOS is. This would result in it working for the simulator and not for the device.